# How to make static directory in Django

Tags: django, django-staticfiles

I created static directory which included css and image files in my Django project. When I run my project the css do display("GET /static/website/barber.css HTTP/1.1" 200 69) but the images do not("GET /static/website/images/balloons.gif HTTP/1.1" 404 1840),

Answer (score 3):

in your `setting.py` file define `STATIC_URL`

```
STATICFILES_DIRS=[
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'static'),
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'boot'),
]
STATTC_URL = '/static/'
```

and add this to your `urls.py`

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    #your url
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Comment: now I'm getting this error: Not Found: /index
[15/Apr/2022 01:44:43] "GET /index HTTP/1.1" 404 3141
Not Found: /contact
[15/Apr/2022 01:45:05] "GET /contact HTTP/1.1" 404 3149

Comment: now I'm getting this error:                                                                                                Not Found: /index
[15/Apr/2022 01:44:43] "GET /index HTTP/1.1" 404 3141
Not Found: /contact
[15/Apr/2022 01:45:05] "GET /contact HTTP/1.1" 404 3149

Comment: Share the whole code to discover the problem

Comment: which aspect of the code should i post?

Comment: model ,view, urls

Answer (score 1):

### Add STATIC settings

You need to create these definitions in **settings.py** to tell Django where is static files:

```
STATIC_DIR = os.path.join (BASE_DIR, "static")
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join (BASE_DIR,'static files')

STATIC_URL ='/static/'# path to read css with local (probably)
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
        os.path.join (BASE_DIR, "static"),
    ]
```

---

### Be sure to import settings and static in urls.py.

You also need to add them to your main **urls.py** to access the URLs of images:

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static  

urlpatterns = [ 
    #Your urls
]

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Comment: I added and run but had this error: (staticfiles.W004) The directory '/home/nyantakyi/PROJECTS/mysite/static' in the STATICFILES_DIRS setting does not exist.