# How to add static files for a specific path in django

Tags: python, django, django-static

I am a noob when it comes to django or any backend related programs.
i would like to add the same static files for a path which is not home in my django project.

Here I am in my howe directory and there is no issues with loading static css and js file.[home page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lsk4Q.png)
but if i try to move to another path[other link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U0XMM.png) static file are not loading.
how can i load same static files but for different url other than the homepage

I even added another folder named loading in my working dir but am still unsuccessful

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make static directory in Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71873839/how-to-make-static-directory-in-django)

Comment: Please show the code. settings.py, urls.py, template and so on. Take a look at any of similar questions. And/or take a look at django docs https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/howto/static-files/

Comment: thank you all for the answers i get around this problem by loading the static files into the template using {% load static%}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Django By default takes a static path from app directory, But you can change your custom static path like this...

##### If you go with the default path then the below setting works fine.

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

##### If you want to set your custom static path then you need to add the below line.

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = ['relative path of your static folder']
```

Comment: i got around it by just loading static into the template. Thank you for your help